# Which stripe API must be used when customer recieves money from owner of stripe account?

Tags: stripe-payments

In laravel 5.8 app with stripe/stripe-php: ^7.50 when customer  pays for provided services it works with code:

```
   \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey( config('app.STRIPE_TEST_KEY') );
   $user = User::where('id', $request->user_id)->first();
   $customer_id = $user->stripe_customer_id;

    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
        'amount' => $request->amount * 100, // Say $request->amount= 50
        'currency' => $request->currency,   // USD
        'customer' => $customer_id
    ]);
    TransactionsTable::create([
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'type' => $request->card['brand'],
        'amount' => $request->amount,
        'currency' => $request->currency,
        'transaction_id' => $charge->id,
        'status' => $charge->status
    ]);
```

And USD 50 is subtracted from customer card and is added to the owner of stripe account (in dev app.STRIPE_TEST_KEY)

But if in case when customer recieves money from owner of stripe
account (customer earned some maney on the site)
which API can I to use?
The same API/code( \Stripe\Charge::create) with negative sum or other api must be used ?
I do not know can I call this operation as refund or other operation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to send money back to a Customer object like that, so you'd likely just need to hold it as a credit to use against future payments.

Or maybe you need Connect, depending on what it is you're building: https://stripe.com/docs/connect

Comment: I tried to read docs in the link, but it seems too common for me. are there some examples with  stripe/stripe-php on this issue ?

Comment: The docs are full of examples including examples with PHP code such as these: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide https://stripe.com/docs/connect/add-and-pay-out-guide